# iterate over large mongodb collection for purpose of updating schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a 300k collection of test docs. I want to update all persons `firstName` and `lastName` to be lowercase.

```
  const person = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String},
  lastName: { type: String }

})
```

I've added `lowecase:true` to the schema but how do I update the existing documents?

I tried:

```
  CaseFile
  .find({ })
  .cursor()
  .eachAsync(async function (doc) {
    await doc.save()
  })
```

but i get the error

```
Error: Collection method find is synchronous
```

I also tried :

```
   CaseFile
  .find({ })
  .then(docs => {
    docs.forEach(doc => {
      doc.save()
    })
  })
```

which gives the error:

```
JavaScript heap out of memory
```

db version v5.0.2

"mongoose": "^6.0.5",

thank you Wernfried Domscheit for the pipeline  solution:

```
CaseFile.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set:
    {
      firstName: { $toLower: '$firstName' },
      lastName: { $toLower: '$lastName' }
    }
  }]
)
  .then(res => res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on earth "iterate", i.e. line by line?

Use an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.CaseFile.updateMany({}, [
   { $set: 
      firstName: { $toLower: "$firstName" },
      lastName: { $toLower: "$lastName" }
   }
])
```